# Como usar uma API em um projeto no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, api

alguém tem algum tuto falando sobre isso, ou podem me explicar dando algum exemplo?
Procurei na net mas tudo estava meio que sem noção, então vim aqui pra saber mais. alguem se habilita a responder por favor?

valeu gente..

Comment: Qual API você que usar?

Comment: Cada API é um caso. "Como usar" também é muito genérico. Faça uma pergunta mais específica para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Bem Pablo, é que sou novo no android, então tenho duvidas quanto ao que seja uma api e como utilizar... por isso vim aqui...

Comment: @Legolas Como você sabe que precisa de uma API? A gente precisa saber o que você quer fazer para poder ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

A google oferece várias APIs, por exemplo:

Se sua aplicação vai trabalhar com mapas, no seu projeto (lado esquerdo no android studio) vá em Gradle Scripts e abra o arquivo build.gradle ("Modulo seu app"). No final deste arquivo tem uma cláusula dependences, dentro desta cláusula você adiona as APIs que deseja usar, no nosso exemplo seria

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
  ...
}
```

tem outras APIs de mapa

com.google.android.gms:play-services-location - pra trabalhar com o GPS

com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils - pra converter coordenadas geográficas em endereço e vice-versa

Dê uma olhada em:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Valeu Edson...então uma api é isso? Valeu...agora sei o que é e como usar..

Comment: @Legolas Primeiramente, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, que bom que teve uma luz ai no seu problema, você só precisa dar uma olhadinha no [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do site pra ver como devem ser feitas as perguntas, pra que sempre fiquem bem claras e alguém possa te ajudar sem precisar fazer mais perguntas